# How to replace even or odd colums in a matrix?

Tags: r

For, example I if a had matrix like this:

```
realmatrix=matrix(1:16,ncol=4,nrow=4)
```

Which would give this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

And I would like to make a function that would replace the two columns with a certain value ( for example 1:4) if it has a even number of colums, then the result should be something like this:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  1    1    1   13
[2,]  2    2    2   14
[3,]  3    3    3   15
[4,]  4    4    4   16
```

And if the matrix has odd numbers of colums, the function should replace only the odd column, that is to say the central one:

This is the matrix with odd numbers of columns:

```
realmatrix2=matrix(1:12,ncol=3,nrow=4)
```

The final result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    9
[2,]    2    2   10
[3,]    3    3   11
[4,]    4    4   12
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your matrix have 5 columns or 6 columns, then, which columns should be replaced?  The rules are not very clear.  You said replacement only for odd column.  Are you looking for replacing the middle columns in odd and even number of column matrices?

Comment: If the matrix has odd number of columns, replace the central one.

If the matrix has even numbers of columns, replace the two central. one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  fun2 <- function(mat, val){
          stopifnot(length(val)==nrow(mat))
           n <- ncol(mat)
           if( (n/2) %%2 ==0){
           mat[, c(n/2, n/2+1)] <- val
            }
           else {
           mat[, ceiling(n/2)] <- val
           }
           mat
          }

  fun2(realmatrix, 1:4)
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
   #[1,]    1    1    1   13
   #[2,]    2    2    2   14
   #[3,]    3    3    3   15
   #[4,]    4    4    4   16


  fun2(realmatrix2,1:4)
  #       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  #[1,]    1    1    9
  #[2,]    2    2   10
  #[3,]    3    3   11
  #[4,]    4    4   12

  realmatrix5=matrix(1:32, ncol=8,nrow=4)
  fun2(realmatrix5, 1:4)
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
  #[1,]    1    5    9    1    1   21   25   29
  #[2,]    2    6   10    2    2   22   26   30
  #[3,]    3    7   11    3    3   23   27   31
  #[4,]    4    8   12    4    4   24   28   32
```

#### Update

If you want to change the rows:

```
 funR <- function(mat, val){
        stopifnot(length(val)==ncol(mat))
        n <- nrow(mat)
        if((n/2) %%2==0){
        mat[c(n/2, n/2+1),] <- rep(val, each=2)
         }
         else {
        mat[ceiling(n/2),] <- val
         }
        mat
        }


 funR(realmatrix, 1:4)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    5    9   13
 #[2,]    1    2    3    4
 #[3,]    1    2    3    4
 #[4,]    4    8   12   16


 realmatrix3 <- matrix(1:15, ncol=5)
  funR(realmatrix3, 1:5)
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    1    4    7   10   13
 #[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
 #[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
```

Comment: Can you make that a function for both cases, which looks at the matrix and determents if it has even or odd numbers, and then makes the replacement?

Comment: How would the exact same thing look for rows?

Comment: @Trik23 Updated with a row function